How to handle data persistence with local storage when the data structure changes?
I'm building a web application that uses local storage to store user data and application state. However, I'm facing an issue when the structure of the data changes between versions of the application.
For example, let's say I initially stored an array of user objects in local storage, with each user object having properties like name, age, and email. In the next version of the application, I need to add a new property address to the user objects.
The problem is that when the application loads, it tries to parse the data from local storage using the new data structure, which causes an error because the existing data in local storage doesn't have the address property.
Here's a simplified example of the code:
// Initial data structure
const initialUsers = [
  { name: 'John', age: 30, email: 'john@example.com' },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 25, email: 'jane@example.com' }
];

// Save initial data to local storage
localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(initialUsers));

// Later, when the app loads with the new data structure
const storedUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
// Error: storedUsers[0].address is undefined

// New data structure with the added 'address' property
const newUsers = [
  { name: 'John', age: 30, email: 'john@example.com', address: '123 Main St' },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 25, email: 'jane@example.com', address: '456 Oak Ave' }
];

I've tried various approaches, such as checking for the existence of the new property before accessing it, but I haven't found a satisfactory solution that handles all edge cases.
What is the best practice for handling data persistence with local storage when the data structure changes between versions of the application? How can I ensure that the application can gracefully handle data migration and avoid errors or data loss?

storedUsers[0]?.address??"" that way the result should always be a string

The question lacks the actual line firing the said error. Accessing a non-existing property of an object does not trigger any errors (unless a method call isn't done, which in this case is not possible), what exactly are you doing to get that error message?

if address property doesn't set initially it can't be accessable . check if the address property is setting initially.
